# G suite marketplace app installation in domain install, offers to uninstall instead of launch the app

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

Up until a few days ago, when an admin wanted to install our app in `Domain Install` (we have individual install option disabled for out app), after auth the marketplace then allowed him to Click a green `LAUNCH` icon to complete the process.

This was now replaced with a greyed out "Uninstall" button and a strange red instruction the says `Please uninstall app for domain in Admin Console`.

This looks like a critical bug. It prevents us from completing the install process since the admin is not redirected back to our portal to complete the installation and we are not notified of the install.
This is reproducible in multiple apps/computers/g-suite tenants.

1. Is this a known issue? it's a regression from last week.
2. Is there an alternative way for allowing the admin user to install and launch the app for his domain (and get redirected back to my portal as part of it)?

**It used to look like-**

[image: Before this week]

**Now it look like-**
[image]